# Selenium not loading keyboard properties when press DOT in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium webdriver 2.52 and already imported all necessary JAR files to my project.

As code writing tool I am using Eclipse. I am having some test case where I want to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key by selenium. I know code for it but when I write

**Keys.** , It loads other properties but not showing Enter, Return keys in list. Even if I write forcefully **Keys.ENTER** , It shows read line. 
Am I missing any configuration?

I have already added : `import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;`

Comment: How about using robot class?

Comment: @PankajKatiyar - Not yet tried but looking for solution with Keys.

Comment: @HelpingHands Does it load other keys like SHIFT, CONTROL, etc.? And is there any namespace conflict?

Comment: @amitbobade-  loads other namespace like Equal, click etc. But not loading any keyboard related properties.

Comment: @HelpingHands sorry but looks like I need some more information. Can you paste all the import statements you are using and the code you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can do by below methods

1. Use send keys and use as press enter like below. Feel free to change locator according to your need

> ```
> driver.findElement(By.id("Value")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
> ```

use import as below:-

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
```

2. Using robot class but it is not recommended as it is not as much reliable. It will not work if your browser is minimized

   ```
   Robot robot = new Robot();
   robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
   robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
   ```

   Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thanks for help , Actually issue is it does not allow Keys.Enter , OR if I write Keys and press dot , in that list it is not showing any properties related to key press. For ex: Enter, Return , Tab etc.

Answer (score -1):

I was facing similar problem, when i created a object after that when i want to accept keywords after enter object. then after dot no suggestions, the problem is i was trying to work directly under class , but first i suppose to create method then i can enter inside method then it worked me.

Comment: This is extremely low quality. What does *work directly under class* mean? Can you add a code sample, or something?